# Skype 4.3.0.37 stopped working after installation of Nvidia 340.32 drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, skype

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and tried skype, it worked.

Now I decided to install the video driver from NVIDIA website, install went successful but now Skype is not starting anymore, no error, nothing.

Any help to diagnose this problem, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Problem fixed, typed 'skype' in terminal and the result was: 'skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64' then found the solution searching google for this error.

Answer (score 4):

I think this wrapper script is one way to make it work:

Create the folder `bin` in your home directory, if it's not there already, and put a file named `skype` there with this contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 $LD_PRELOAD"
exec /usr/bin/skype "$@"
```

Make the file executable with:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/skype
```

If you needed to create the `~/bin` folder, you need to log out and log in again for this to make a difference.

This should work however you choose to start skype.

Comment: Another option is to add `alias skype='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 skype'` line to `.bashrc` file.

Comment: @Akavall: Right, but then it won't work if you start skype in the graphical environment, e.g. by clicking an icon.

Comment: to give control back to the shell, add an ampersand: `exec /usr/bin/skype "$@" &`

Comment: @Milimetric: Right, that's useful if you start the program from the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of messing with all that, create a file called `local.conf` in the subdirectory `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`

In `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf`, add the following line:

```
/usr/lib32
```

Now `sudo ldconfig`

In Later versions of Ubuntu the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` file contains `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`.  If this didn't work, ensure that line is added.

Comment: Appending /usr/lib32 to the file /etc/ld.so.conf worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Skype relies on 32 bit libGL.so.1.On a 32-bit OS it will work without any problems.This problem is seen for those who uses the 64-bit Operating System.As I said before, skype relies on 32-bit libGL.so.1.But it first finds the 64 bit libGL.so.1 file and tries to use it for the rendering, which results in the above error : `wrong ELF class`.
What to do is listed in this [link](http://www.pctips4u.com/2014/02/skype-not-working-on-64bit-linux.html#.VVwiVuQabCI).

Open the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/skype.conf` as listed below.

```
sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/skype.conf
```

Then append the line `/usr/lib32`( Or your path, if yours is a different one).

After running `sudo ldconfig` it should work without a problem.
Check the link which I listed before for more information.

Comment: It is important to add only the path to the directory, and not to the file. On ubuntu 15.04 created `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/skype.conf` (you have cd into `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` because `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` is a text file) and added this line: `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

Answer (score -2):

This solution worked for me on Debian 8

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

Comment: Ubuntu's Mesa installation uses different paths.