# Problems after installing Skype 4.3

Tags: skype

just installed Skype 4.3 on my laptop (Dell Inspiron N5110) running Ubuntu 14.10 following all the instructions from every possible source  but when I try to launch it absolutely nothing happens.

What can I do to get it working? Here's what I get:

```
andi@Andi:~$ skype
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What output do you get if you open a terminal window and run the command `skype`? Please answer by editing your question and adding that piece of info.

Comment: Here's what I get " andi@Andi:~$ skype
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory "

Comment: I suggest that you check out this solution: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233005

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open a terminal window and try to start Skype with this command (copy and paste):

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 skype
```

If that's successful, I suggest that you check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520507) to get a persistent solution.

Comment: Thank you! I did as you said and it worked! My Skype is running gr8 now!

Comment: @MateiAlexandru: Great! Then can you please "accept" my answer, so others see that the problem was resolved.

Comment: sorry to bother you yet again, but what do you mean by "accepting" your answer? I'm kinda' new around here, I switched to linux a few days ago and I ain't very familiar with the procedures :)

Comment: I've sorted it out! Thank you once again for your help

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo ln -st /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu mesa/libGL.so.1
```

Make sure you have `libgl1-mesa-glx` installed.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `libgl1-mesa-glx` needs to be installed. After installing it, everything worked for me even without making symlinks or setting `LD_PRELOAD` (though in my case it was Firefox inside a Docker container that didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

For **Ubuntu like systems**, I confirm that the solution of Gunnar Hjalmarsson works:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 skype
```

(tested un xUbuntu 16.04) However, it doesn't work for debian.

The solutions for **debian** are listed [here](https://wiki.debian.org/skype), and the solution for the libGl error is to run

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

Then everything works perfectly ! (tested on debian unstable with the debian binary from the official website on november 2016)

Answer (score -1):

If others like me ends up here trying to solve this problem, the solution could be to reinstall bumblebee with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia --reinstall
```