# Skype mysteriously reverts to trying the 64-bit libGL.so.1 (and failing)

Tags: 64-bit, skype, 32-bit, mesa, ld

After my last `apt-get dist upgrade` (which installed a new version of the kernel, but not much beyond that), my Skype (which used to work) now says:

```
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

meaning it's probably looking at some 64-bit version of that file. Now, here's what I have:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1.0.0
```

with

```
update-alternatives --display i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf
i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf - manual mode
  link best version is /usr/lib/nvidia-367/alt_ld.so.conf
  link currently points to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
  link i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf is /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf
  slave i386-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules is /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf - priority 500
  slave i386-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/x11-extra-modules
/usr/lib/nvidia-367-prime/alt_ld.so.conf - priority 8603
/usr/lib/nvidia-367/alt_ld.so.conf - priority 8604
```

and there's also:

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/skype.conf 
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/
```

So, why is Skype not finding the right library?

I tried explicitly preloading the version Skype seems to want, as suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/555948/606721), i.e.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 sykpe
```

but that gives me

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

PS - My system is Kubuntu 16.04 with CUDA 8 and nVIDIA drivers installed not through distro packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/a/555948/606721

Comment: @ThatGuy: Apparently not, see edit.

Comment: What about this: http://askubuntu.com/a/322347/606721

Comment: @ThatGuy: See edit. Doesn't look like this will help either.